# How to disable intelllisense errors in vscode when using macros defined with -D flag?

Tags: c++, macros, compiler-flags

I have a CMake file which defines PROJECT_PATH macro for my project with the -D flag. I want to be able to use that macro in code to access a file relative to that path, like this:

```cpp
auto file = open_file(std::string(PROJECT_PATH) + 'path/to/the/file.txt');
```

Is there any way to disable the intellisense error messages only for that particular macro?

Edit: I have found a dirty solution which works for now:

in the .vscode/settings.json I added:

```json
    "C_Cpp.default.defines": [
        "${default}",
        "PROJECT_DIR=\"\"" // dirty hack to disable intellisense errors 
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To let IntelliSense know about your macros, you must create the file `c_cpp_properties.json` in your `.vscode` folder.

There you can specify your macros in the field `"defines"`. However, this is not perfect because you have to do it twice, once in the build and once here.

A better approach is to use `"compileCommands"`, where you can set the path to file `compile_command.json`, where will be placed all macros from the build. CMake automatically generates this file if you turn it on with the `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` definition.

**c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        // macro defined only for intelisense. It won't be used for build
        "defines": [
            "MY_DEFINE=\"some_text\""
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x86",
        // owerwrite inlucdes and defines with values used from build
        "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ]
        }
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(TestArea VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

add_compile_definitions(MY_DEFINE="some/path")

add_executable(TestArea test.cpp)
```